# Finding the (symbolic) eigenvalues of a matrix with some assumption

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, assumptions, eigenvalues

I have the following 3$\times$3 symmetric matrix with symbolic entries.

Meff =
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 \beta  \text{c12}^2 \text{c13}^2 \text{$\eta $11} \text{m1}+\alpha  \text{c13}^2 \text{D31} \text{s12}^2+2 \beta  \text{c13}^2 \text{$\eta $11} \text{m2}
   \text{s12}^2+\text{D31} \text{s13}^2+2 \beta  \text{$\eta $11} \text{m3} \text{s13}^2 & \alpha  \text{c12} \text{c13} \text{D31} \text{s12}-\beta  \text{c12}
   \text{c13} \text{$\eta $11} \text{m1} \text{s12}+\beta  \text{c12} \text{c13} \text{$\eta $11} \text{m2} \text{s12} & \beta  \text{c12}^2 (-\text{c13}) \text{$\eta
   $11} \text{m1} \text{s13}-\alpha  \text{c13} \text{D31} \text{s12}^2 \text{s13}+\text{c13} \text{D31} \text{s13}-\beta  \text{c13} \text{$\eta $11} \text{m2}
   \text{s12}^2 \text{s13}+\beta  \text{c13} \text{$\eta $11} \text{m3} \text{s13} \\
 \alpha  \text{c12} \text{c13} \text{D31} \text{s12}-\beta  \text{c12} \text{c13} \text{$\eta $11} \text{m1} \text{s12}+\beta  \text{c12} \text{c13} \text{$\eta $11}
   \text{m2} \text{s12} & \alpha  \text{c12}^2 \text{D31} & \alpha  (-\text{c12}) \text{D31} \text{s12} \text{s13} \\
 \beta  \text{c12}^2 (-\text{c13}) \text{$\eta $11} \text{m1} \text{s13}-\alpha  \text{c13} \text{D31} \text{s12}^2 \text{s13}+\text{c13} \text{D31} \text{s13}-\beta 
   \text{c13} \text{$\eta $11} \text{m2} \text{s12}^2 \text{s13}+\beta  \text{c13} \text{$\eta $11} \text{m3} \text{s13} & \alpha  (-\text{c12}) \text{D31} \text{s12}
   \text{s13} & \text{c13}^2 \text{D31}+\alpha  \text{D31} \text{s12}^2 \text{s13}^2 \\
\end{array}

I want the eigenvalues of the above matrix but Mathematica gives very long expressions for eigenvalues if I use `Eigenvalues[Meff, Cubics -> True]` which is not understandable. I want to make certain approximations, for example, I want to ignore some terms in eigenvalues that are in higher powers of say $\alpha$ and $s_{13}$ and so on just like we truncate the expressions up to certain orders in some parameters. How to do that? Sorry if I am not able to make the problem understandable. Below is the Mathematica code for the matrix (Meff)

```
R13 = {{c13, 0, Exp[-I*z13]*s13}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Exp[I*z13]*s13, 0, 
    c13}};
U13 = {{c13, 0, s13}, {0, 1, 0}, {-s13, 0, c13}};
R12 = {{c12, s12, 0}, {-s12, c12, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
R23 = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, c23, s23}, {0, -s23, c23}} ;
Dnu = {{m1, 0, 0}, {0, m2, 0}, {0, 0, m3}};
Mass = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, D31*α, 0}, {0, 0, D31}};
Udelta = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, Exp[I*z13]}} ;
Udeltadag = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, Exp[-I*z13]}} ;
UB = U13.Udeltadag.R12; 
UBdag = Assuming[{s12, s12, s23, c12, c13, c23, z13, α, 
     D31, β, m1, m2, 
     m3, η11, η22, η33} ∈ Reals, 
   TrigToExp[Simplify@ComplexExpand[ConjugateTranspose[UB]]]];
delm1 = β*{{η11, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
M1 = UB.Dnu.UBdag.delm1 + delm1.UB.Dnu.UBdag;
Mtotal =  UB.Mass.UBdag + M1 ;
Meff =  Assuming[{s12, s12, s23, c12, c13, c23, z13, α, 
     D31, β, m1, m2, 
     m3, η11, η22, η33} ∈ Reals, 
   TrigToExp[FullSimplify@ComplexExpand[Mtotal]]]
Eigenvalues[Meff, Cubics -> True]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work and `Eigenvalues` stays unevaluated. You need to remove `// MatrixForm` from `Meff` - it's for presentation purposes only.

Comment: Done. Can you try with "Mtotal" it is same as "Meff"?

Comment: You can start off with something like this `eigs /. {Power[s12, n_] /; n > 1 :> 0, 
  Power[\[Alpha], n_] /; n > 1 :> 0}` which will work in most cases except for where you have radicals.

Comment: Maybe use `Series` on the eigenvalues

Comment: @flinty Thank you for the suggestion. And yes, this approach seems to work a bit. Can you tell me if I want to ignore some combinations of terms lets us say I want to ignore products of $\alpha\times\beta\times m1 $ and $\alpha \times \beta\times  \eta$ and so on, then what command should I give?

Comment: @neuoscman Add another rule to the list `m1 α β -> 0` . Mathematica will put them in that order `m1 α β` I think but check this. Also if you want to repeatedly apply the rules to simplify further, use `//.`

Comment: Thanks again@flinty. Is there a way that I can define that $\alpha, m1, \beta$ and so on are of some order let us say $10^{-1}, 10^{-2}$ etc and I want those terms in the expression (including the products of $\alpha, m1, \beta$ and so on) which gives order up to $10^{-4}$ and ignore higher order terms.